# How to put a button on a new line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
            
            <div class="pagination">
             
            </div>
            <button type="button" onClick={$("#error-text").hide()} class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

where the HTML for the pagination class is set later. This gives me something that looks like this in my modal
[image]

Howeer I want the close button to appear below the other elements. I am wondering how to achieve this in CSS, I have already tried using another  to contain the button as well as style:block

Comment: If you can edit your HTML, just wrap it in a block element like a div. By wrapping it in a div, you will have more control over the spacing and alignment too.

Comment: What is the CSS for pagination?

Comment: did you tried flex box?

Comment: For testing, could you provide us the *generated* HTML, including the pagination buttons?  That said, off the top of my head, you might accomplish what you want with a judicious `display: block;`

Comment: More specifically: `button.btn-secondary { display: block; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the best ways to do this is ***flexbox***. I highly recommend learning it.

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
        
        <section class="pagination">
        <span>1 2 3</span>
         <div>
           <button>
           next
         </button>
         <button>
         last
         </button>
         </div>
        </section>
        <button type="button" onClick={$("#error-text").hide()} class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.pagination{
   display:flex;
   gap:10px;
  }
 .modal-footer{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-items : flex-start;
   justify-content:center;
   gap:10px
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 
 to insert a line break in the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">

<div class="pagination">

</div>
<br><button type="button" onClick={$("#error-text").hide()} class="btn btn-secondary" data-     dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: This is not recommended.